# In Debian bullseye, does systemd-timesyncd check for other ntp daemons?

Tags: raspbian, chrony, systemd-timesyncd

I've used `systemd-timesyncd` as my system timekeeper for several years now. I run a Debian *derivative* called **raspbian** for my Raspberry Pis. I'm mostly very pleased with the SNTP client that is `systemd-timesyncd`, but would like to experiment with `chronyd` for use in off-grid applications.

The following command may be used to list the configuration of `systemd-timesyncd`:

```bash
$ systemctl cat systemd-timesyncd
```

In **buster**, there was a section of code in this listing that provided `systemd-timesyncd` with the ability to "excuse itself" if it found another timekeeping service (NTP daemon) installed:

```
# /lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d/disable-with-time-daemon.conf
[Unit]
# don't run timesyncd if we have another NTP daemon installed
ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/ntpd
ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/openntpd
ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/chronyd
ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/VBoxService
```

At ***some point*** after the release of **buster** (concurrent w/ release of **bullseye**??), the above scheme was altered; the command `systemctl cat systemd-timesyncd` no longer contains any references to restricting or inhibiting startup of `systemd-timesyncd` if other timekeepers are found.

Does anyone recall the history of this change?  More importantly, does `systemd-timesyncd` still inhibit its startup if it finds another timekeeping daemon installed? Where/how is this done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `systemd-timesyncd` service no longer checks for conflicts itself. Instead, the conflict is handled by having `systemd-timesyncd` in its own package, [which conflicts with other time service packages](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1115332/accepted-systemd-2454-2-source-amd64-into-unstable-unstable/): it’s therefore now impossible to have two time servers *installed* (using Debian packages).

The way this works, in more detail, is that the `systemd-timesyncd` package has a `Conflicts: time-daemon` entry. [`time-daemon` is a virtual package provided by all time daemons](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/time-daemon), and they all conflict with it so that only a single time daemon can be installed at once (packages can’t conflict with themselves so the apparent self-conflict isn’t a problem). This is the standard mechanism in Debian to ensure that a single package of a set providing a given feature is provided. The package split is significant because such a package conflict couldn’t be defined on the `systemd` package itself.

This might seem more fragile, since it doesn’t deal with manually-installed time servers. However those aren’t supposed to go in `/usr/sbin` anyway, so the previous scheme wouldn’t have handled them either. On top of that, automatically enabling and disabling time daemons proved unreliable, and [it didn’t seem possible at the time to fix that](https://bugs.debian.org/947936).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! If you could clarify something for me, I'd appreciate it: How is it that putting `systemd-timesyncd` in "its own package" makes it impossible to install (as in `apt install xxxx`?) - for example - `chrony`??

Comment: The `systemd-timesyncd` package has a `Conflicts: time-daemon` entry; `time-daemon` is a virtual package provided by all time daemons. This is the standard mechanism in Debian to ensure that a single package of a set providing a given feature is provided. The package split is significant because such a package conflict couldn’t be defined on the `systemd` package itself.

Comment: You're right (of course :) - I just tried to `apt install chrony`, and got this message: *"The following packages will be REMOVED:  `systemd-timesyncd`"*. I have to say I'm not entirely happy with that approach as it limits *my prerogatives* for using whichever package was most appropriate at a specific time. I guess this gets into `systemd-politics` though, so let's drop it. :)

Comment: Right, installing and removing packages is “heavier” than enabling or disabling daemons... Unfortunately the latter couldn’t be handled automatically in a reliable way, see [#947936](https://bugs.debian.org/947936) for the gory details.

Comment: "Heavy" it is... this sounds like a number of other `systemd` issues... but I'm going to follow my advice & let it go at that. :)

Comment: @Seamus: It's a Debian thing. Long before systemd, I remember you couldn't install two SMTP daemons (e.g. Exim and Postfix) for the same reason – package-level conflicts – even if you weren't going to run both; or even if you needed both for different reasons. (Now, they do both provide the same /usr/lib/sendmail but that could've been solved with a split package, _especially_ in the land of "exim consists of 10 packages" Debian.)